# Authenticate via spring LDAP with additional security check in database

Tags: spring, authentication, jdbc, spring-security, ldap

After LDAP authentication, I want to check against the database if the user ID is listed on the user table.

How can I accomplish this? All I can see all over Google is authentication via LDAP and user roles retrieval on the database.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your way of having the user Prancipal :

You will keep you ldapProvider :

```
<beans:bean id="ldapProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
```

....

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsMapper" class="xxxxx.CustomUserDetailsMapper">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="customUserDetailService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailService" class="xxxxxx.CustomUserDetailService">
</beans:bean>
```

define a custom UserDatailsMapper :

```
public class CustomUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

private UserDetailsService userDetailService;

public CustomUserDetailsMapper (UserDetailsService userDetailService) {
    this.userDetailService = userDetailService;
}

@Override
public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx,
        String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

    return (UserDetails) this.userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
}
```

}

and define also a Custom UserDetailsService :

```
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {


@Autowired
protected UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserDb user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);

    if (UserDb  == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }           

    // Construct customUserDetails

    return (UserDetails)customUserDetails;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Spring Security so I appreciate some explanation. Where does the `UserDetails` come from?

Comment: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails it's a core Interface from spring security

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree Hello SciasTwentyThree have you achieved your object  ive? I am looking for similar tight security for DB layer after LDAP authentication, would be great if you could share your answer - Thanks